# IvyDe doesnt use ivysettings.xml per project

Tags: ivyde

When trying to set up IveDE, i'm running into the problem that i need to specify my ivysetting.xml on the workspace level in order for my resolvers (to local nexus) to work.

I was hoping there is some way to get IvyDE to use the ivysettings.xml of the project.

I've added the path to my ivysetting through

```
Project --> properties --> ivy --> retrieve list --> edit --> settings tab
```

This gives no errors but doesnt make ivyde use the ivysettings provided for the project.

Is it somehow possible to get IvyDE to use a different ivysettings.xml for each project and if yet how?

Edit: this seems to have been a eclipse cache issue.(see self answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the real problem i was having.

My ivysettings.xml changed locations in on of the projects, i updated the retrieve pattern (which i may nog even need) and didnt change the ivyDE eclipse classpath container. by editing that one everything seems to work as intended

```
(Project --> properties --> buildpath --> libraries)
```

I probably missed this because i was looking at the ivy properties of the project instead

Answer (score 1):

IvyDE supports two kind of dependencies: the retrieved ones and the classpath container ones. The first is to do a retrieve of some dependencies in the project (not necessarily java), the second is to get jar dependencies into the java classpath of the project.

Looking at the way you configured your project's ivy settings, we configured a retrieve one. Probably you wanted to setup a classpath container ? To do so, cf:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/cpc/create.html

Comment: no i have a classpath container, but looking for to a way to specify the settings on a project by project basis (they differ somewhat)

Comment: for some reasong it actually seems to work properly now